# I would like to click on New Contact button from web page for my selenium script

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I would like to click on a "New Contact" button for my selenium script.  I have tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btn-group.contact_list-menu-contact_add")).click();
```

And by `xpath` as well, but it is not working.  How could I get this working?

```
<div class="btn-group left">
<a id="contact_list-menu-contact_add" class="Button btn-contactadd primary SaveItem" href="javascript:">New Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's quite hard to help you without `HTML` for target button and exception log

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Below is the code            <div class="btn-group left">
<a id="contact_list-menu-contact_add" class="Button btn-contactadd primary SaveItem" href="javascript:">New Contact</a>
</div>

Comment: Your id is `contact_list-menu-contact_add` use as :-`driver.findElement(By.id("contact_list-menu-contact_add")).click();`

Comment: thanks saurabh,, i have tried that as well it is giving exception element not found

Comment: @SatyanarayanaPola ok then try with `webDriverWait` to wait until element visible...see I have posted it as an answer..:)

Comment: @SatyanarayanaPola come back and let us know your problem has solved or still remain...If ut has solved please accept the anyone of these correct answer and make this question as solved. Thanks...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting `NoSuchElementException` as you have mentioned in the comment, There are may be two reason :-

- May be when you are going to find element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, So you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible and clickable as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("contact_list-menu-contact_add")));
  el.click();
  ```
- May be this element is inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding the element as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("contactURL"));
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("contact_list-menu-contact_add")));
  el.click();
  ```

**Edited** :- As I see from your provided HTML this button is inside `<div id="btn-new-group" class="btn-group-actions left" style="display: none;">` which is set to be invisible, that's why you are not able to find button. You should make it visible first then try to find as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("contactURL"));
WebElement invisibleDiv = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("btn-new-group")));

//Now make it visible first
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", invisibleDiv);

//Now find contact button
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("contact_list-menu-contact_add")));
el.click();
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: thanks saurabh.. still i have an error   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 40 seconds waiting for frame to be available: frame id or name
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'

Comment: @SatyanarayanaPola Did you look for the frame??..may be it is inside a frame..try second option..

Comment: ya saurabh .. i tried second option by giving frame id from page source Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 40 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: contact_list-menu-contact_add
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'

Comment: And i have only one frame for page

Comment: <div id="Contact" class="Part Show">
<div id="ContactIFrame" class="Container" style="height: 258px;">
<iframe id="contactURL" width="100%" height="258px" style="border: 0px none; height: 258px;" src="https://book-t2.jiodrive.ril.com/web/home.htm">

Comment: @SatyanarayanaPola I have updated second option with your provided frame I'd...now try with it and let me know

Comment: thanks saurabh, I have tried with query provided but no luck even by providing 40 seconds time out..error::: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 40 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: contact_list-menu-contact_add
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'

Comment: @SatyanarayanaPola see once provided Id is correct or not?? And did you try to switch frame before finding element???

Comment: ya element id is correct and i have used switch to frame URL below is the code i have tried

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame("contactURL"); WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("contactURL")); WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("contact_list-menu-cont‌​act_add"))); el.click(); – Satyanarayana Pola 13 mins ago

Comment: @SatyanarayanaPola you are going wrong. Omit `driver.switchTo().frame("contactURL");` line..because `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("contactURL"));` this line doing same work..you are going to switch frame two times.. so omit first line..

Comment: Just do `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("contactURL")); WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("contact_list-menu-cont‌​‌​act_add"))); el.click();`..

Comment: tried that as well ...am sorry.. not sure where am doing mistake

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 40 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: contact_list-menu-contact_add

Comment: @SatyanarayanaPola are you sure your `contact_list-menu-contact_add` is inside the iframe??

Comment: ya saurabh am sure it is inside iframe. any option to post total page html source. please suggest

Comment: Could you share your link??

Comment: I want to click on contact_list-menu-contact_add              https://www.dropbox.com/s/fuz0zyc6jggrx1z/code.txt?dl=0

Comment: @SatyanarayanaPola Ok as i seeing in your provided HTML this button is inside `<div id="btn-new-group" class="btn-group-actions left" style="display: none;">` which is invisible, so make it visible first then find button...try with edited answer..may be it works..:)

Comment: Saurabh bhai thanks for your fantastic support and finally u made it work.. one hting is instead of find element by id i have used javascript to find element and it is working :)

Comment: @SatyanarayanaPola You welcome. Glad to help you..Please accept the answer as well...:)

Answer (score 2):

You are searching by an incorrect `id` value, use `contact_list-menu-contact_add` instead:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("contact_list-menu-contact_add")).click();
```

Or, by a *CSS selector*:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn-group .btn-contactadd")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn-group #contact_list-menu-contact_add")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#contact_list-menu-contact_add")).click();
```

Or, by a *link text*:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Contact")).click();
```

---

If the target element is inside an iframe, you would need to *switch into the context of the frame* before searching for the element. Assuming that your frame has `contactURL` id, this is how to switch to it:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("contactURL");
```

Comment: thanks alecxe.. following exception am getting                                                  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#contact_list-menu-contact_add"}
Command duration or timeout: 40.18 seconds